# number of permutations with k inversions modulo 3

Tags: combinatorics

**Let 0 ≤ k ≤ 2. Show that for n ≥ 3, the number of permutations
w ∈ Sn whose number of inversions is congruent to k
modulo 3 is independent of k. For instance, when n = 3 there are
two permutations with 0 or 3 inversions, two with one inversion,
and two with two inversions.**

This is a problem from EC1 additional problems.
I tried to use recursive relations:

$i(n,k)$: number of permutations in $S_n$ with exactly $k$ inversions.

$$i(n+1,k)=i(n,k)+i(n,k−1)+i(n,k−2)+⋯+i(n,k−n).$$
But it seems to be too complicated.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generating function for the permutations by inversion is
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}x^{\textrm{inv}(\sigma)}=(1+x)(1+x+x^2)\cdots
(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1})$$
where $\textrm{inv}(\sigma)$ is the number of inversions
of the permutation $\sigma$.

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_m x^m$ with the $a_j$ real.
Define $b_0=a_0+a_3+a_6+\cdots$, $b_1=a_1+a_4+a_7+\cdots$
and $b_2=a_2+a_5+a_8+\cdots$. Then $b_0=b_1=b_2$ iff $f(\exp(2\pi i/3))=0$.

Comment: Thank you for you quick and clear answer. It helps a lot!